# how to detect the exact line that the eror is happening

Tags: reactjs, react-native, atom-editor

I am having problems with finding the exact line that I have issues, I use atom, for instance in the attached image what does that 16:8 mean? is that the line number?

[image]

Comment: Line 16 column 8 I'd guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16:8 means it's line 16 on the `Input.js` file and on the 8th character. Most editors use 'Column' instead of character. I used VSCode, so for me at the bottom right I have Ln 16, Col 8. That's where the unexpected token is. Good luck!